# how to update add +1 to a field in all of ActiveRecord selected rows

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, phpactiverecord

i have a code like this:

```
 $ads = Ad::find('all', array('order' => 'select_visits desc', 'limit' => 20, 'conditions'=>array('active = 1')));
```

i want to update all of $ads, select_visits field to select_visits+1, how can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

One easy way (the activerecord way) is to go through the results of your finder, change and save them, but's that's extremely inefficient.

I'd use a direct SQL statement, using the Connection class, like this:

```
Ad::connection()->query('UPDATE ads SET select_visits=select_visits+1 WHERE active=1;');
```